# Why doesn't Integer.parseInt("1")++ work in Java?

Tags: java, integer, int

I've got the following line of code:

```
suffix = suffix.isEmpty() ? "1" : Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(suffix)+1);
```

in a block where suffix has already been declared as an empty String (`""`). The block is looking for duplicate file names and adding a number on to any duplicates so they don't have the same name any more.

The line of code above compiles fine, but if I change it to this,

```
suffix = suffix.isEmpty() ? "1" : Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(suffix)++);
```

I get `Invalid argument to operation ++/--`. Since `Integer.parseInt()` returns and int, why can't I use the `++` operator?

Comment: Basically, this is just because you cant write the code line: `1++;`

Comment: apart from why it doesn't work (see the answers), you wouldn't get the value you wanted anyway - since `n++` is the **post**-increment, meaning that the value of `n` would be returned and then 1 added to it...

Comment: @nyarlathotep: Not quite.  Even in an expression like `n++`, the increment doesn't *happen after* the value is returned.  It's just that the value that results from the expression is the value that `n` had before being incremented.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: thanks for clearing that up, that's what I was thinking, I just couldn't formulate it as concisely as you did :D

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `++` operator should update the value of its argument, so the argument should have a *fixed* position in memory to be updated. For this reason, the argument should be a variable*. In this case, the argument is `Integer.parseInt(suffix)`, has no fixed memory address to be updated at all.

Intuitively, `Integer.parseInt(suffix)++` is roughly equivalent to `Integer.parseInt(suffix) = Integer.parseInt(suffix) + 1`. But `Integer.parseInt(suffix)` is just an integer value, not associated to a fixed position in memory, so the code above is almost the same thing of, let us say, `32 = 32 + 1`. Since you cannot assign a new value to `32` (neither to `Integer.parseInt(suffix)`) then there is no sense in supporting the `++` operator.

The good news is that this does not cause any problems at all! Instead of `Integer.parseInt(suffix)++`, write `Integer.parseInt(suffix)+1`.

*  Or, as it is most commonly called, an [*l-value*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29), or an *address value*.

Comment: That is why C and C++ introduced concepts like *lvalue* and *rvalue*. Every expression is either lvalue or rvalue in C and C++. Is there any such concept in Java?

Comment: @Nawaz although it is better known by C++ programmers, the concept is language-independent. Java has l-values - for example, variables when they are set and attributions all are l-values. However, Java does not have a way to put a l-value in a variable, as you could do in C++.

Comment: Does the language specification of Java talk about lvalues? Also what do you mean by this "*Java does not have a way to put a l-value in a variable, as you could do in C++*"?

Comment: @Nawaz AFAIk no, the Java language spec does not. (There is a mention on the [Java EE 5 spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html) about l-values in ELs, however.) Also, I mean that you cannot create reference variables in Java as you can in C++. (Actually one cannot "put l-values in variables" - except for pointers, in a sense - so I bet my choice of words was a bit poor in this aspect :) )

Comment: R-values ARE associated with a fixed position in memory, just not modifiable.

Comment: @paislee not necessarily: a R-value may be stored e.g. in a register, it can be loaded from the object code to different positions of memory, although being the same value etc. More important, a r-value (which is not eligible to be l-value, obviously) has no fixed memory position _in the model of the language_. You cannot do, for example, `int *i = &3;` in C or `int &i = 3;` in C++. The storage of a r-value is an implementation detail that is explicitly hidden by the language - so, even it has such a position (which is not necessary and even unlikely), it does not exist to the developer.

Answer (score 13):

++ requires an lvalue (an assignable value).

`Integer.parseInt(suffix)` is not an lvalue.

Note that `i++` is not the same as `i+1`.

Answer (score 10):

The `int` is an rvalue. Since it isn't bound to a variable you cannot use post-incrementation.

Comment: The 'int' *isn't* an lvalue. It's an rvalue. All lvalues are 'bound to variables'. Answer makes no sense.

Comment: @EJP fixed. It's odd, I made the same stupid brain fart (rvalue/lvalue) multiple times yesterday, I think I might be getting ill or something. Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 10):

Writing i++ is a shortcut for  i=i+1; if you were to 'read it in english' you'd read it as "i becomes current value of i plus one"

which is why 3++ doesn't make sense you can't really say 3 = 3+1 (read as 3 becomes current value of 3 plus one) :-)

Answer (score 8):

`++` expects an assignable value, i.e. a variable. `Integer.parseInt` returns a value that cannot be assigned. If you need a value plus one, use `Integer.parseInt(suffix)+1` instead.