# Invalid argument to operation ++/--

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, hashmap

I want to do some operations on the `HashMap<String, Integer>` belonging to an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>`. But I got the following error: *Invalid argument to operation ++/--* when doing ths `logEntry.get(key) ++` as following:

```
....
Integer tempSize = ...;
List<HashMap<String, Integer>> tokenCollection = new ArrayList<>(tempSize);
while(tokenCollection.size() < tempSize) {
    tokenCollection.add(new HashMap<String, Integer>());
}
....
for (int i = 0; i < tempSize; i++) {
    String key = ...;
    HashMap<String, Integer> logEntry = tokenCollection.get(i);
    if (logEntry.containsKey(key)) {
      logEntry.get(key) ++; // ERROR
    } else {
      logEntry.put(key, 1);
    }
}
```

Then, I have to change the code into the following one, and it works:

```
    if (logEntry.containsKey(key)) {
      Integer tempValue = logEntry.get(key);
      tempValue++;
      logEntry.remove(key);
      logEntry.put(key, tempValue);
    } else {
      logEntry.put(key, 1);
    }
```

But this adds lots of additional operations. Can I avoid this? Also, I think my way of doing this is too complex or stupid, is there any simpler way?

Comment: Wasn't meaning to close this as a dupe - just to point out that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536223/why-doesnt-integer-parseint1-work-in-java is a similar question.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom thanks for your commits. it was a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the other answers already stated, you can't mutate the key directly.
But you can shorten your code even more:

```
logEntry.put(key, logEntry.containsKey(key) ? logEntry.get(key) + 1 : 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't mutate the value of the `Integer` already stored in your `Map` for a given key, since `Integer` is an immutable type.

You can, however, shorten your code :

```
if (logEntry.containsKey(key)) {
  logEntry.put(key, logEntry.get(key) + 1);
} else {
  logEntry.put(key, 1);
}
```

1. There's no need to remove the key from the map before putting the same key with a new value.
2. You can increment the value and put the new value in the map in the same statement.

Another option (that eliminates the call to `containsKey`) :

```
Integer value = logEntry.get(key);
logEntry.put (key, value != null ? value + 1 : 1);
```

Comment: At last, someone mentions that `Integer` is immutable! :-)

Comment: Just doing my part to make our universe a wonderful place to be :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can shorten your code to

```
if (logEntry.containsKey(key)) {
    logEntry.put(key, logEntry.get(key) + 1);
} else {
    logEntry.put(key, 1);
}
```

which at least removes the explicit deletion.

Java unfortunately does not have the language syntax to enable you to retrieve an element *by reference* (which would permit incrementation *through* the reference), as you can in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Why map.get(key)++ doesn't compile but Integer i =1; i++ works:

https://bukkit.org/threads/invalid-argument-to-operation.336350/

increment and decrement operators only work on variables, not values.

- Just like 1++ doesn't compile